# does a derived class object contain private members of the base class? What does it look like in memory?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix, derived

```
class base{
private:
  int a;
public:
  int b;
  void setData(){
    a = 10; b = 5;
  }
};
class derived: public base{
private:    
   int c;
public:
  // b is inherited
};

void main(){
  derived D1;

  D1.setData();
}
```

I learned that private members aren't inherited. So, the private variable a (in the base class) is not present in the derived class object. My question is **when D1.setData() is called, how can it assign a value to a, if a doesn't exist?
I'm pretty sure I have this concept wrong, so can some one explain how this works? Are the base class members also created when the derived class object is created?**

Comment: They are inherited, however they are inaccessible. Try debugging, putting a breakpoint around your object and looking at it during runtime, you'll get an idea of how it looks!

Answer (score 1):

> I learned that private members aren't inherited.

Of course they are inherited: otherwise, all member functions of the base class that need these private variables would be broken. Although private members are not accessible to the inheriting class, the base class retain full access to them.

> Can some one explain how this works?

Layout of the inheriting class `derived` includes a place to store `a`, the private member of the base class. All methods of the base class can access `base::a`. At the same time, it remains inaccessible to the derived class: any attempt to access `a` from `derived` would cause a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Private member variables are inherited, but cannot be accessed externally. The memory pattern of inheritance is simple:

```
class base {
    int x;
};

class subclassCpp : public base {
    int y;
};

class subclassCStyle {
    base a;
    int y;
};
```

Now, `subclassCpp` and `subclassCStyle` have the exact same memory pattern, regardless of private/protected status, etc. This should illustrate how the memory is laid out.

For the other question, "Are the base class members also created when the derived class object is created?"

The answer is yes, a constructor is always invoked on the base class. If you don't add this yourself, the default constructor is automatically invoked. If the base class doesn't have a default constructor, it won't let you create a subclass constructor that doesn't properly invoke whatever constructor is necessary to initialize the base. So there is no legal way you can end up with a base class that hasn't been initialized when the subclass was created, as long as a constructor in the subclass was executed.

Comment: It should not be called `subclassCStyle` as this is still done and has it's uses in C++ or other OO languages. You can either inherit or aggregate a class, both are different things and can be interpreted differently when making object models.
If class B inherits from class A this means that object of class B is a kind of object of class A, for example: circle is a kind of geometric shape.
If class B aggregates class C this means that object of class B contains object of class C, for example: circle contains a point (the origin)

Comment: C style polymorphism / inheritance are googlable terms. Now obviously, putting a class within another class as a field is super common and valid. But trying to reinvent polymorphic casting in C++ is not really endorsable. In the pattern you are describing, why wouldn't you just get the contained object through an accessor or by accessing the field instead of casting to base? This is why your example is not C-style inheritance.